# PHP - Unable to implement the same interface twice

Tags: php, oop, interface, extends

I am trying to Implement an interface twice which extends another interface but unable to figure out why i am getting a **Fatal Error**

Here's my code:

```
interface a {
    public function foo();
}

interface b extends a {
    public function baz(Baz $baz);
}

// This will work
class c implements b {
    public function foo() {
    }

    public function baz(Baz $baz) {
    }
}

// This will not work and result in a fatal error
class d implements b {
    public function foo() {
    }

    public function baz(Foo $foo) {
    }
}
```

I am getting this error message:

**Fatal error: Declaration of d::baz() must be compatible with b::baz(Baz $baz) in K:\xampp\htdocs\oop\Lec 2\index.php on line 26**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class d has implemented the `baz` method incorrectly. The interface specifies it must take an argument with the typehint `Baz` but you use the typehint `Foo` - changing the argument type from the interface is disallowed. The fix, in class d, would be:

```
<?php

class d implements b
{
   public function foo() {}
   public function baz(Baz $foo) {}
}
```

The function's args are specified by the interface, and may not change.

Comment: Thanks @Erik i got it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not Java, you can't (unfortunately) overload methods. So, in the end having something like

```
class d implements b
{
   public function foo()
   {
   }

   public function baz(Foo $foo)
   {
   }

   public function baz(Baz $baz)
   {
   }
}
```

Will result in

> **Fatal error**:  Cannot redeclare d::baz() in **[...][...]** on line **XX**

When implementing an interface, you **must** implement it the same way it is declared. So, since `baz` is declared with `Baz $baz` argument, you **must** implement it with same argument.

```
class d implements b
{
   public function foo()
   {
   }

   public function baz(Baz $baz)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: I am grateful. It helped @Nordenheim